# Accessing Pivot table data in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I have 3 tables in database named **tbl_product_manager, tbl_tags, tbl_categories**. **tbl_product_manager** and **tbl_categories** are linked to one to one relations and **tbl_tags** and **tbl_product_manager** is linked with **many to many relations** with pivot table **tbl_product_tag**. I had used eloquent for this. I am able to perform insert and update operation in those tables but I am stuck in viewing data through HTML.

**This is my controller code for view:**

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $productList = ProductManagementModel::getAllProducts();

     //var_dump($productList); die();

    $i = 1;
    $products = '';
    foreach($productList as $product) {
        $products .= '<tr class="odd gradeX">';
        $products .= '<td>'.$i++.'</td>';
        $products .= '<td>'.$product->product_name.'</td>';
        $products .= '<td>'.$product->category_name.'</td>';

        $products .= '<td>'.$product->product_cost .'</td>';

        if($product->is_active=='1') { 
            $products .= '<td>'.'<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="unpublish-selectedproduct" id="'.$product->id.'" >'.
                     '<span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-ok"></i></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp'.'</td>';
        } else {
            $products .= '<td>'.'<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="publish-selectedproduct" id="'.$product->id.'" >'.
                     '<span class="label label-warning"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp'.'</td>';
        }
        $products .= '<td>'.$product->updated_at.'</td>';
        $products .= '<td>'.
                    '<a href="product_management/edit/'.$product->id.'"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.
                    '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete-selectedproduct" id="'.$product->id.'" >'.
                    '<i class="icon-trash" ></i> Delete</a>'.'</td>';
        $products .= '</tr>';

    }

    return View::make('admin.product_management.list', array('products' => $products));
}
```

Model of table **tbl_product_manager**

```
   <?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class ProductManagementModel extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
    protected $table = 'product_manager';

    public function categories(){
        return $this ->hasOne('CategoriesModel','id');
    }

    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('TagModel','id');
    }

    public static function getAllProducts(){
            return $product = DB::table('product_manager')
             ->join('categories', 'product_manager.category_id', '=','categories.id')
             ->select('product_manager.id', 'categories.id','product_manager.*', 'categories.category_name')
             ->groupby('product_manager.id')
             ->get();

    }
    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('TagModel', 'product_tag', 'product_id', 'tag_id');     
    }
}
```

Model of table tbl_tag

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class TagModel extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tags';
    public function productManagement()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('productManagementModel');
    }

    public static function getAlltags() 
    {
        return $tags = DB::table('tags')
               ->get();     
    }
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('productManagementModel', 'product_tag', 'tag_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

model of pivot table tbl_product_tag

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class ProductTagModel extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
    protected $table = 'product_tag';
    public $limit;   
    public static function productTags()
    {
        return $productTag = DB::table('product_tag')
                    ->get();        
    }   
}
```

I am making the html view in controller itself. I want to use eloquent for to access the data of tbl_tag which is linked with the pivot table and the parent table(tbl_product_manager) is also linked with the pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show how are you trying to display tags. Looks like you just to display all tags for each product. In this case, [load the data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$products = ProductManagementModel::with('tags')->get();
```

And then display it:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    {{ $product->name }}
    @foreach ($product->tags as $tag)
        {{ $tag->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```